# How to start Server user authentication in PHP and Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, authentication

I had a production server which used to authenticate user before granting access. I setup a new machine and copied files from the old server. Now, I can access pages fine, but it does not ask for username and password. When I checked the value of `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` is returns nothing.

Is a way to activate it on the server or I missed any file while copying it from old server ?

Comment: Did you make sure to copy hidden files as well?

Answer (score 0):

So, where is the list of user names and passwords? is it a flat file, in a database? you can't implement something you cant find.

Comment: The list of username and password are stored in DB.

Comment: I noticed this is tagged .htaccess have you enabled mod_auth_mysql?  (http://modauthmysql.sourceforge.net/) What does your .htaccess file look like?